# How to construct a matrix with desired properties in C#

Tags: c#, matrix

I need to construct a matrix with ((X.size)^ncol) x ncol dimension.
Where X is an array and `X.size` is the size of that array

`ncol` represents number of columns.

Inputs given would be an array(say "X") and number of columns (say "ncol") of desired matrix.

I think writing  down the properties will create confusion, so I would like to give few examples of desired matrix with given inputs:

example 1:

Inputs: array X = `[1,2,3]` and desired number of columns are  2

then my output should be

```
    Var1 Var2
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    2    1
 [3,]    3    1
 [4,]    1    2
 [5,]    2    2
 [6,]    3    2
 [7,]    1    3
 [8,]    2    3
 [9,]    3    3
```

example 2:

Inputs: array X = `[1,2,3]` and desired number of columns are  3

```
     Var1 Var2 Var3
 [1,]    1    1    1
 [2,]    2    1    1
 [3,]    3    1    1
 [4,]    1    2    1
 [5,]    2    2    1
 [6,]    3    2    1
 [7,]    1    3    1
 [8,]    2    3    1
 [9,]    3    3    1
[10,]    1    1    2
[11,]    2    1    2
[12,]    3    1    2
[13,]    1    2    2
[14,]    2    2    2
[15,]    3    2    2
[16,]    1    3    2
[17,]    2    3    2
[18,]    3    3    2
[19,]    1    1    3
[20,]    2    1    3
[21,]    3    1    3
[22,]    1    2    3
[23,]    2    2    3
[24,]    3    2    3
[25,]    1    3    3
[26,]    2    3    3
[27,]    3    3    3
```

example 3:

Inputs: array X = `[1,2,3]` and desired number of columns are  1

then desired output should be

```
    [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Read [ask] for information on how to write a good question. What you have here is pretty much a list of requirements.

Comment: @dandan78, Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited my question after reading your suggested link. I hope my question makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to enumerate all combinations of `nCols` symbols from the given array.

This can be done quite easily with the following observation: The elements in the first column repeat once. The elements in the second column repeat `symbols.Length` times. In the third column `symbols.Length^2` and so on.

Filling this matrix can then be done in several nested loops like the following:

```
// Calculate the needed number of rows
int nRows = (int)Math.Pow(symbols.Length, nCols);

// Allocate memory for the matrix
int[,] matrix = new int[nRows, nCols];

// The first column repeats elements exactly once
int repeatedElementsInCol = 1;

//Successively fill all columns
for (int col = 0; col < nCols; ++col)
{
    int row = 0;
    // Fill every row
    while(row < nRows)
    {
        // Write each symbol to the matrix ...
        foreach (var symbol in symbols)
            // ... with the specified number of repetitions
            for (int repetition = 0; repetition < repeatedElementsInCol; ++repetition)
                matrix[row++, col] = symbol;
    }

    // The next column repeats elements symbols.Length times as often
    repeatedElementsInCol *= symbols.Length;
}
```

This gives the following matrix for `nCols = 3` and `symbols = { 1, 2, 3 }`

```
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  1  1
1  2  1
2  2  1
3  2  1
1  3  1
2  3  1
3  3  1
1  1  2
2  1  2
3  1  2
1  2  2
2  2  2
3  2  2
1  3  2
2  3  2
3  3  2
1  1  3
2  1  3
3  1  3
1  2  3
2  2  3
3  2  3
1  3  3
2  3  3
3  3  3
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Nico. Problem which I was trying to slove since yesterday afternoon , you made it look so simple.